# -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient only for left border

Tags: html, css, safari, webkit

Here CSS:

`-webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, transparent, #f9f9f9 20%, #f9f9f9 80%, transparent) 0 0 0 1;`

It't displaying as:

[image: Wrong]

How to make it as

`border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, transparent, #f9f9f9 20%, #f9f9f9 80%, transparent) 0 0 0 1;`

[image]

Comment: What about `border-width: 0; border-left-width: 5px; `?

Comment: Nope, no result.

Comment: Questions seeking help ("**why isn't, or how to make, this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a _specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: That can be done (most likely) in another way...working cross browser, so if you post the code I might be able to help

Comment: >[LGSon](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2827823/lgson)

Here [code](https://codepen.io/Zekfad/pen/zwmXOp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it like 2 `absolute` and `inline-block`'s:

CSS

```
.menu {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
.menu:before {
    content: " ";
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    border-left: 1px solid;
    border-image: linear-gradient(to top, transparent, #f9f9f9 20%, #f9f9f9 80%, transparent) 0 0 0 1;
    border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, transparent, #f9f9f9 20%, #f9f9f9 80%, transparent) 0 0 0 1;
    border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, transparent, #f9f9f9 20%, #f9f9f9 80%, transparent) 0 0 0 1;
    -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, transparent, #f9f9f9 20%, #f9f9f9 80%, transparent) 0 0 0 1;
}
```

[{Full code}](https://codepen.io/Zekfad/pen/zwmXOp)